# Firebase rule to avoid parent overwrite

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my db, I have a node like this on root:

```
-dbroot
--usernameuid
---user1:'someid'
---user2:'someid'
---user3:'someid'

...
```

for creating this I am using code below:

```
database().ref('usernameuid/' + that.state.username).set(auth().currentUser.uid).then(() => {

...
```

Recently, I am not sure how it happened but somebody managed to delete or overwrite all `--usernameuid` node.

As my investigation, I found out blank username passed despite i am checking username with regex.

Anyway, firebase got blank username (that.state.username) and overwrote like `--usernameuid: 'someid'` and all data gone.

For prevent this not to happen again in future, (app is live so cant modify code) what kind of firebase rule can i write for:

1. user can only add **child** to `--usernameuid`
2. **can't** overwrite all like `--usernameuid: 'something'`
3. **can't** delete anything under `--usernameuid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",

...


   "otherchild1": {
      ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
      
      
    },

   "otherchild2": {
      ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
      
      
    },

...

         "usernameuid": {
          "$username" : {
             ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
          }
      
      
    },
```

Summary: No rule at parent, specify .write in child you want. But on root, you need to delete global .write rule and specify seperately for each child hence firebase does not support cascade rules.